# Assigning expressions to a Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have a good question on the ternary operator, I was trying to give an expression a different value. But I got an error, I've never tried doing that with a ternary operator before, until today. Why can't I have expressions be the result of the ternary operator?(I know it takes functions as well) And is there a specific reason why they didn't release JavaScript to have this ability?

```
function chessboard(x, y){
    var board = '';
  var picker = true;
  for(var i = 1; i < y+1; i++){
    var j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++){
        picker ? board += '#';picker= false; : board += ' ';picker= true;
      board += '\n';
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

Comment: Try with the comma operator. But I'd suggest just using an `if` as it looks pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the assignments to

```
board += picker ? '#' : ' ';
picker = !picker;
```

while it makes more clear what's happen.

Otherwise this would work (but i do not recommend it!):

```
picker ? (board += '#', picker = false) : (board += ' ', picker = true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why don't you recommend it?

Comment: because of the assignments, it makes the code not shorter and the readability is bad and it is prone to mistakes.